# Write a for loop that calculates the sum of numbers i to n in R

Tags: r, loops

Im trying to write a loop that calculates the sum of the numbers 0:200. What I have come up with is just printing the sum, 200 times:
`Y <- 0:200 for(n in Y) {Y <- sum(Y) print(Y)}`
I want the loop to only return the value 20100 and it must be a for loop. Thanks!

Comment: You know you can just do `sum(0:200)`

Comment: I assume this is an exercise in loop programming. In order to get the sum at the end of loop, you'll want to store the intermediate results in a variable (the Y in your code is overwritten each iteration). For example: Within the loop, on each step, add the current value to the current sum and save that. Then on the next step, add the next value to the result from the previous step... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
sum_i <- 0
for (i in 1:200) {
  sum_i <- sum_i + i
}

sum_i
[1] 20100
```

Comment: Yes thank you! Why does including print(sum_i) inside {} print the cumulative sum for each i but if you run it outside the loop it only returns 20100? Thanks.

Comment: In my example we create `sum_i` variable equal to 0, then FOR i = 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 200 we add this `i` to `sum_i`, and only after all that `sum_i` is called. If you want to call `sum_i` from inside the for loop, then you will call its intermediate value after adding each `i`. Calling it from inside the for loop is possible, if you add a condition. For example, adding `if (i == 200) { print(sum_i) }`, but that's just redundant.